# QPushButon not showing when using move() method PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I have a simple window which is supposed to reproduce a sound, and when I create the QPushButton, it shows in the top left corner like it's supposed to, but when I use the move() over any of them, they just don't show up anymoer in the Window.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setup()
def setup(self):
    self.musica = QSound('sounds/gorillaz.mp3')
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
    self.boton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.boton.setText('Reproducir')
    # self.boton.move(300, 100)
    self.boton2 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.boton2.clicked.connect(self.musica.play)
    self.boton2.setText('DETENER')
    self.boton2.move(400, 100)
    self.boton2.clicked.connect(self.musica.stop)
    self.setWindowTitle('PrograPoP')
    self.resize(750,600)
```

Why is this happening? Maybe is there another method I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe is there another method I should be using?

Yes, you should almost always use [Qt's layout mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). I have converted your example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python #in newer versions is not necesarry I think, but it's always worth doing

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, 
    QPushButton, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setup()

def setup(self):
    self.musica = QSound('sounds/gorillaz.mp3')
    self.mainWidget = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    self.mainLayout.addSpacing(100) # Add some empty space above the buttons.
    self.buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.buttonLayout)

    self.boton = QPushButton(self.mainWidget)
    self.boton.setText('Reproducir')
    #self.boton.move(300, 100)
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.boton)
    self.boton2 = QPushButton(self.mainWidget)
    self.boton2.clicked.connect(self.musica.play)
    self.boton2.setText('DETENER')
    #self.boton2.move(400, 100)
    self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.boton2)
    self.boton2.clicked.connect(self.musica.stop)
    self.setWindowTitle('PrograPoP')
    self.resize(750,600)

def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that I renamed your `centralWidget` to `mainWidget`, otherwise the line `self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)` overrides the [QMainWindow.centralWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) method definition, which will give you an error.

Comment: Thanks, that's great,but if I need to move to a certain pixel position? And can I have more than one layout in a Widget? Because, as far as I understand, the one you applied is a horizontal one

Comment: The position (and size) of your widget typically depends on the size of the window. Without using layouts you will have to recalculate this yourself whenever the window resizes. This is the functionality that layouts offer you and that is why you (almost) always use them. You can use nested layouts with the `addLayout` method. I've updated my example. Other options are to use a `QGridLayout`